# Parsing ASPX site with Python POST request

Tags: python, asp.net, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to perfom parsing but when I send POST method to get searching results, getting page with error:
The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.

Website: https://prod.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG/CEIDG.Public.UI/Search.aspx

I've collected data like viewstate, viewstategenerator etc.. to pass throught form but doesn't work.
What am I missing?

```
#import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import urllib
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
import time
#s = HTMLSession(browser_args=["--no-sandbox", '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'])
s= HTMLSession()
header_simple = {
'User_Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
    'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

}

r = s.request('get', 'http://prod.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG/CEIDG.Public.UI/Search.aspx')
soup_dummy = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
# parse and retrieve two vital form values
viewstate = soup_dummy.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
viewstategen = soup_dummy.select("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")[0]['value']
eventvalidation = soup_dummy.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']
english = soup_dummy.select("#hfEnglishWebsiteUrl")[0]['value']

data = {
'__VIEWSTATE': viewstate,
'__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': viewstategen,
'__EVENTVALIDATION': eventvalidation,
'ctl00$MainContent$txtName': 'bank',
'ctl00$MainContent$cbIncludeCeased': 'on',
'ctl00$MainContent$btnSearch': 'Find',
'ctl00$hfAuthRequired': 'False',
'ctl00$hfEnglishWebsiteUrl': english,
'ctl00$stWarningLength': '30',
'ctl00$stIdleAfter': '1200',
'ctl00$stPollingInterval': '60',
'ctl00$stMultiTabTimeoutSyncInterval': '20'
}
time.sleep(3)
p = s.request('post', 'https://prod.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG/CEIDG.Public.UI/Search.aspx', params=data, headers=header_simple)

print(p.content)
```

Comment: Did you try using requests?

Comment: Hello @SIM, yes just tried to make it from request.session(). Same

Comment: You posted screen scraping code. This has nothing to do with parsing nor is it affected by what server-side framework is used to generate the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the ways how you can populate results from that page using requests module. Be sure to include all the keys and values within data parameters while sending with post requests in order to access the desired content.

Working script:

```
import lxml
import requests
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
    
    r = s.get('http://prod.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG/CEIDG.Public.UI/Search.aspx')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
    data = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}

    data['ctl00$MainContent$txtName'] = 'bank'
    data['ctl00$MainContent$cbIncludeCeased'] = 'on'
    data['ctl00$MainContent$btnSearch'] = 'Find'
    data.pop('ctl00$MainContent$btnClear')
    data.pop('ctl00$versionDetails$btnClose')

    # pprint(data)   #print it to see the keys and values that have been included within data

    p = s.post('https://prod.ceidg.gov.pl/CEIDG/CEIDG.Public.UI/Search.aspx', data=data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(p.text,"lxml")
    print(soup.select_one("table#MainContent_DataListEntities"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much SIM, with your help I found out my the biggest mistake, in post request I pass params=data instead of data=data. This is was the main issue)